# Android CarrierMessagingService does not receive text message event

Tags: android

I implemented a CarrierMessagingService like that:

```
public class MyService extends CarrierMessagingService {

    public void onReceiveTextSms(@NonNull MessagePdu pdu, @NonNull String format,
                                 int destPort, int subId, @NonNull final ResultCallback<Integer> callback) {
        Log.i("MyService","onReceiveSms");
    }
}
```

With this manifest:

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_SERVICES">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.carrier.CarrierMessagingService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Then I sent myself a sms. I expected to reach the log that i put in the method  onReceiveTextSms of the CarrierMessagingService...However I did not reach it. Why is that?

Comment: did my answer solved your question? if yes you should accept the answer, if not explain why so I can try to help you further

Answer (score 1):

The [android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_SERVICES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_CARRIER_SERVICES) is a `privileged` permission.

You can't be granted this permission even if you declare it in the manifest. It is reserved to carrier or OEMs.

> You can read more info about privileged permissions [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist)

Comment: Yes, if the app is a system app you can use this permission. You should add your app to the whitelisted ones which can access this permission. You can find all the needed informations in the link I posted in my answer